# Unity/C# - Cannot move backwards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controls

I'm new to Unity/C#, working on a script for PS4 controller, to get my character to be able to move in any directions using left stick and aim using right stick.

I used raycast to prevent my avatar from going through walls; that solved my issue of walking directly through walls.

However, when I aimed with right stick and moved in an opposite direction with my left, it still passed through the walls.

To tackle that, I adjusted the raycast parameter by adding the direction of the left stick (movement).

That worked, but it gave birth to a bug - I couldn't move backwards directly at all.
Diagonal-backs were fine, but I simply cannot move backwards in an open space.

Here is my code:

`using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic; using UnityEngine;`

```
public class NewMove : MonoBehaviour
{
Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
public float m_Speed = 10f;
public float DashStamina = 100f;

void Start()
{
    //Fetch the Rigidbody from the GameObject with this script attached
    m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Left Stick Input - Movement
    float HorizontalMovementInput = Input.GetAxis("LStickHorizontal");
    float VerticalMovementInput = Input.GetAxis("LStickVertical");

    // Right Stick Input - Aim
    float RSHorizontalMovementInput = Input.GetAxis("RStickHorizontal");
    float RSVerticalMovementInput = Input.GetAxis("RStickVertical");

    Vector3 CharDirection = new Vector3(HorizontalMovementInput, 0, VerticalMovementInput);

    if (Input.GetButton("SubMovement") && DashStamina > 1)
    // Dash speed
    {
        Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + CharDirection, fwd, 3) == false)
        {
            //Store user input as a movement vector
            Vector3 m_Input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("LStickHorizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("LStickVertical"));

            //Apply the movement vector to the current position, which is //multiplied by deltaTime and speed for a smooth MovePosition
            m_Rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + m_Input * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (m_Speed * 2));

            DashStamina -= 0.5f;
        }


    }
    else
    // Normal running speed
    {
        Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + CharDirection, fwd, 3) == false)
        {
            Vector3 m_Input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("LStickHorizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("LStickVertical"));
                            
            m_Rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + m_Input * Time.fixedDeltaTime * m_Speed);

            DashStamina += 0.05f;
        }
    }

    //Faces Archer to last direction of left stick
    transform.LookAt(transform.position + CharDirection);

    //Faces Archer to aiming direction of right stick; will override above

    Vector3 CharAim = new Vector3(RSHorizontalMovementInput, 0, RSVerticalMovementInput);
    transform.LookAt(transform.position + CharAim);

    DashStamina = Mathf.Clamp(DashStamina, 0, 100);
}
```

}

Please advise.